# Trying to create a trigger to check if there's more than 1 president in my database

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, raiseerror

I'm trying to find if there's more than 1 president in my database with a trigger and if yes, raise an error, I'm using hr, the table employees and I have to use the job_id to find it. Here's what my code looks like. Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_pres
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((employees.job_id = 'AD_PRES') > 1)
    THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-12345, 'More than one President in database.');
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Statement Level Trigger` instead of `Row Level Trigger` by removing `FOR EACH ROW` expression

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_pres
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON employees
DECLARE    
    v_cnt int;
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_cnt FROM employees WHERE job_id = 'AD_PRES';

  IF ( v_cnt > 1 ) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20345, 'More than one President in database.');
  END IF;
END;
```

otherwise you'd get mutating error while getting the count value. Btw, the first argument value for `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` should be between `-20999` and `-20000`